# Set resource filters globally in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse

I've started using git externally from Eclipse and have been running into issues with the auto-build functionality trying to compile the hidden .git folders.  This [question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/963/594) shows how to exclude them on a per project basis.  Is there anyway to do this globally or per perspective?

Comment: Did you find a solution in the meantime? I'd be interested if you did. I think it's an essential feature in case you don't want or even are not allowed to change the project settings, but still want to customize your resources - for example, I think it's pretty annoying to get .class files or copied source files from the build process in the open resources box.

Comment: unfortunately not, i just have to go in there for every new project and add the ignore resources.  I've been meaning to see if I can ferret out where that config is stored and write a script to quickly copy it over to a project folder, but haven't had the time yet

Comment: Just to note, there is a [very old ticket](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=301821) for that in Eclipse's issue tracker.

Answer (score 1):

There is currently no such possibility.

When you create a Resource Filter it modifies the `.project` file of your project folder inside the workspace, however I do not recommend creating those filters manually, since they have an ID generated by Eclipse and the chance that you have problems is greater. It is preferable to put the properties individually in each project than to do this directly in the configuration files.

As [@brandizzi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/287976/brandizzi) said in the question comment, there is an [open bug](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=301821) a few years ago but eclipse did not prioritize this in the development of the new versions, dealing with an improvement with low priority, however in my opinion would be another great feature to facilitate the settings of the development environment.

As the tool is very good and free we can not criticize much, but it's the **tip** for [Eclipse.org](https://www.eclipse.org/):

#### There are many developers wanting this functionality.

---

#### Reference:

- [Eclipse Workbench User Guide > Concepts > Workbench >
  Resource filters](https://help.eclipse.org/kepler/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.user%2Fconcepts%2Fresourcefilters.htm)